# How to show all the available options for a PowerShell command?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-7.3

For example, this command:

```
get-netadapter -name "WI-FI"
```

shows my WIFI network adapter's details with 5 columns of information about it.

but if i do this:

```
(get-netadapter -name "WI-FI").
```

and then press tab, I can see a whole lot more information about it that show up after the dot.

now this is only a simple example, there are many more commands like that which by default only show a few columns of information.

what is the universal way of showing all of the available information for each command, like all of the available commands that go after the `.` in the example above and with their output? I want to show them in console in a nice way like with `ft -wrap` if possible so I can quickly get a general idea of what information is accessible to me to work with.

I use latest version of PowerShell (7.4 preview) and Windows 11

p.s sometimes pressing tab doesn't work, like in this example:

```
(get-bitlockervolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive).
```

but we can still use `ProtectionStatus` after the dot

Comment: `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler tab complete` (instead of TabCompleteNext) would have tab list all the methods & properties at once, or after a dash for a parameter.

Comment: I use Format-Table : get-netadapter -name "WI-FI" | Format-Table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use `command | gm` (`gm` is an alias for [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)).

In your case you could type `get-netadapter -name "WI-FI" | gm`. This returns to you the name, the methods, and properties of the returning object.

To output all properties with values: `get-netadapter "WI-FI" | Format-List *`

Comment: Hi, thank you, it is useful, @js2010 comment also did something similar, but I want their output too. so for example, for `get-netadapter -name "WI-FI"` I want to see all of the available information that command can generate and tell me about WI-FI network adapter.

Comment: I have added a command to this

Comment: Yes, without the * after format-table or format-list, it will use a format.ps1xml file and only show those properties.